# Android SeekBar can't be full width even set padding 0 in AppCompat 23.1.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, seekbar

when I update android support lib from 23.0.1 to 23.1.0, I find the SeekBar is not full width any more.

this is the test XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:divider="@drawable/space_divider"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:showDividers="middle">

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"/>

    <!-- default SeekBar -->
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <!-- padding=0 -->
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <!-- padding=40 -->
    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:padding="40dp"
        android:progress="50"
        android:progressTint="@android:color/holo_red_dark"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatSeekBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:progress="50"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

It works well under support lib 23.0.1, like following screenshot. SeekBar has default padding, when I set padding=0 manual, it can be full width. and AppCompatSeekBar is not exist yet.

[image]

but under support lib 23.1.0, whether I set how much of padding, SeekBar and AppCompatSeekBar has no any change, like following screenshot.

[image]

so, is this the bug of support lib, any body meet this problem and how to resolve it?

thank you~!

update:
It totally confused me, I just have another test, I create a new project, whether I use AppCompat 23.0.1 or 23.1.0, SeekBar neither can be full width after set padding=0, (the compileSdkVersion is 23, buildToolsVersion is "23.0.1", targetSdkVersion is 23). anyway, I want to know how to make SeekBar full width when set padding=0 not work.

the build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.test.seekbar"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

finally, I just have a sudden thought. why not try modify it by java code. It works! following is the sample code:

```
protected void initViews(Context context) {
    LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(getLayoutResId(), this);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    // set style, just once
    seekBar.setProgress(0);
    seekBar.setMax(0);

    seekBar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);

    // ...
}
```

Comment: ohh.. Guy!! 
I've tried  android:padding="0dp" in style and in view xml and this hasn't helped.

Thank you!

Comment: It works but does any know what's actually going on and why this happens ?

Comment: We can't get equi-efficacious thereby setting the padding in XML?

Comment: This is it.  Thanks.  Ya you just need to override the default padding.

Comment: Setting to 0dp will clip the thumb when in the outer positions. To handle that add android:clipChildren="false" in the parent view.

Comment: This does not work for me even also with android:paddingt="0dp" in the layout.

Answer (score 34):

Set this attributes in `XML`

```
android:paddingStart="0dp"
```

Comment: Maybe `android:paddingEnd="0dp" `for the other side.

Answer (score 28):

Try adding the parameters `paddingStart` and `paddingEnd` to `0dp` in the xml file. If your app is compatible with Rtl you will need to add those in order to visualize the seekBar with no padding otherwise it will show with padding even if using it in a Ltr language.

Comment: However, be aware that padding set to 0dp will clip the thumb when in the outer positions (for instance when the seekbar is taking up the entire width of the screen).

Comment: Good call out Anton. To address this add android:clipChildren="false" in the parent view.

Comment: I use this android:thumbOffset=0dp will not clip the thumb

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
android:paddingStart="0dp"
android:paddingEnd="0dp"
```

Comment: This does not work for me, and not even android:paddingt="0dp".

Answer (score 3):

As Didac mentioned you can set the padding to 0 in xml.

But make sure you set the padding after you set the `progressTint` or `progressDrawable`.

I had a similar problem (where I was setting progressDrawable).  Once I set the padding as 0 after setting the `progressDrawable`, the `seekbar` padding has gone

Answer (score 2):

if you seekBar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0); may be the thumb can't show complete。
First, you should find what result this. In fact, in the seek bar style, you can find this.

```
<style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:indeterminateOnly">false</item>
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/abc_seekbar_track_material</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/abc_seekbar_track_material</item>
    <item name="android:thumb">@drawable/abc_seekbar_thumb_material</item>
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:paddingRight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

so change the style with paddingLeft and paddingRight

Answer (score 0):

You can set padding to 0, but then you need to android:clipChildren="false" on the container layout. Or you can use negative margins on the SeekBar.