# Android: Custom preference remove unwanted padding/margin?

Tags: android, android-preferences

I am creating my own custom seekbar preference. But there is white space on left side of preference widget. How can I get rid of it?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarPrefUnitsRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarPrefValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/seekBarPrefUnitsRight"
        android:gravity="right"></TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekBarPrefUnitsLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/seekBarPrefValue"></TextView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/seekBarPrefBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seekBarPrefUnitsRight"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBarPrefSeekBar"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I highlight with yellow unwanted space.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475281/2354845

Answer (score 0):

you can try to play with negative values of margin or padding on the individual element, depending on your desire.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/widget_frame"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCheckItOut"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="Check it out"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvCheckItOut"
        android:text="Check it out" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="6dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvSeekbarSummary"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="SeekBar"
        android:textStyle="bold" >
    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvSeekbarSummary"
        android:text="Summary" >
    </TextView>

</RelativeLayout>
<SeekBar
   android:id="@+id/seekBarPrefSeekBar"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:progress="100"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

 </LinearLayout>
```