# Customize seeekbar endpoints

Tags: android, android-layout, seekbar, android-seekbar

I want to update seekbar UI such that there will be a vertical lines at both the endpoints of seekbar. I tried this by setting a custom drawable image (horizontal line with vertical lines at endpoints)in  android:progressDrawable attribute but with that seekbar is not visible(only thumb is visible). I also tried creating custom views at left and right of seekbar but with that vertical lines doesn't remain at exact position in different device. Also as seekbar has default left and right padding i need to give margins to show vertical lines exactly at seekbar endpoints which can be different for different device.

What is an ideal approach to achive this requirement?

```
<SeekBar 
android:id="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:maxHeight="@dimen/dp1" 
android:paddingLeft="0px" 
android:paddingRight="0px" 
android:progressDrawable="@color/white"/>

<View
android:layout_width="@dimen/dp1"
android:layout_height="@dimen/dp10"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/dp16"
android:bawrckground="@color/white"
android:id="@+id/view" />
<View
android:layout_width="@dimen/dp1"
android:layout_height="@dimen/dp10"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/dp16"
android:background="@color/white”/>
```

Comment: okay .can you show any prototype ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Currently i can't share image.But Seekbar should simply look like a horizontal line with vertical endpoints.Vertical line should be at right angle to horizontal line.

Comment: Its a xml issue .

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya What issue is there in xml?Basically i want to show vertical lines  at seekbar track(line) endpoints.

Comment: What about below answer ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Vertical lines should exactly be at the seekbar track endpoints position.The problem is that seekbar has some default padding and so the lines are not visible exactly at track endpoint.

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Also vertical line should be at right angle to horizontal line.It should not go below horizontal line.

Comment: @AndroidLearner I have added few sample pictures in my answer. You can try it if this is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you have already answered your question. As you said the difference is only because of left and right padding then you can achieve this by simply changing margins of the views as follows.
Suppose this is your XML:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/seekBar"
        android:background="@android:color/black" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:maxHeight="1dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@android:color/black" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Then just add following lines to your java file:

```
SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.view1).getLayoutParams()).leftMargin = seekBar.getPaddingLeft();
((ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams) findViewById(R.id.view2).getLayoutParams()).rightMargin = seekBar.getPaddingRight();
```

This is definitely not the best solution but yes it's pretty simple.

Here are few pictures of what it looks like
[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]
[image: Image 3]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking something like this?  I have used layout weight with .05 for end points and .90 (%) for the seekbar... also given thumb.  you can change it to your requirement.

[image]

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_wizard_bar"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ButtonBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_margin="18dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".05"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000FF" />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/my_seekbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".90"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxHeight="15dip"
        android:minHeight="15dip"
        android:thumb="@android:drawable/star_big_off"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/oval_shape"
         android:layout_below="@+id/iv_consumericon"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".05"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000FF" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Remove edges**

To get seekbar attached to your vertical lines.. cut off the padding programatically. `my_seekbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);`  : Courtesy 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33475281/705428

Comment: Vertical lines should exactly be at the seekbar visible endpoints position.The problem is that seekbar has some default padding and so the lines are not visible exactly at the endpoint.

Comment: In your case also there is some gap b/w vertical lines and seekbar endpoint.

Comment: This is a new requirement it was not mentioned in your original Question.... However, Android adjust the seekbar based on the thump image size.. so that full thumb is visible. if you remove my custom thumb and take default thumb supported by android... it should do the job  you... .  Other alternative is use Relative layout and put  endpoint views overlapping on the edge of the image.

Comment: I think it is understood from the question-"Also as seekbar has default left and right padding i need to give margins to show vertical lines exactly at seekbar endpoints which can be different for different device."

Comment: i am using default thumb only for now

Comment: Sorry... i didn't understand this part correctly ...   my_seekbar.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);  should do the magic...   Courtesy http://stackoverflow.com/a/33475281/705428

Comment: Try it pragmatically ( not through XML) it works... . i tried it too.

Comment: +one to ur answer..But adding that the thumb cuts when dragged to endpoints..Any way to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

- **[Seekbar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.html) has default left and right padding**

### Solutions

You can use **Programmatic** way .In here, calling `setPadding`.

> The view may add on the space required to display the scrollbars,
>   depending on the style and visibility of the scrollbars. So the values
>   returned from getPaddingLeft(), getPaddingTop(), getPaddingRight() and
>   getPaddingBottom() may be different from the values set in this call.

**Demo XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#54d66a"
         />

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:progress="0"
         android:max="100"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view1"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="10dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seekBar"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Java Class**

*oncreate()*

```
SeekBar SeekBarOb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
SeekBarOb.setPadding(20,0,0,0);
```

**Bad Approach**

Using hard coded Value .Call **[DisplayMetrics](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html)** .

> A structure describing general information about a display, such as
>   its size, density, and font scaling.

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

        int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
        int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;
```

Now For responsive

```
 SeekBarOb.setPadding(DeviceTotalWidth*2/100 ,0,0,0); // add your value
```

**Finally**

[image]

**FYI**

Don't change demo XML , Add this in your java class

```
 DisplayMetrics metrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

    int DeviceTotalWidth = metrics.widthPixels;
    int DeviceTotalHeight = metrics.heightPixels;

    SeekBar SeekBarOb=(SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    SeekBarOb.setPadding((int) (DeviceTotalWidth*.85/100),0, (int) (DeviceTotalWidth*2.10/100),0);
```

Comment: But these aren't focusable widgets.

Comment: Seekbar thumb gets cut off/clipped if I drag it to endpoints when I set padding to 0 .But in screenshot you posted its showing fine.How you able to achieve this? Doesn't thumb gets cut off in your case if you set padding to 0?

Comment: @AndroidLearner Did you use #DisplayMetrics rule there ?

Comment: No I just added padding to 0 using setPadding

Comment: @AndroidLearner For responsive result, you should use  `#DisplayMetrics` .

Comment: @AndroidLearner Check my #FYI section . In here it works fine

Comment: @AndroidLearner if there is any confusion please ask.

Comment: Basically what i want is that vertical lines should exactly attach to seekbar track endpoints  with no gap between them.Also i want that seekbar thumb should not gets cut off when dragged to endpoints.You are adding padding at left and right of seekbar which will make seekbar thumb completely visible when dragged to endpoints  but  will add space between vertical lines and seekbar track.
What i want can  be achieved if someway we can make seekbar thumb stay within track even if it is dragged to endpoints and setting padding to 0..

Comment: @AndroidLearner Okay . Did you get any solutions .